# Flat category - no image

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, flat-catalog

I have a strange issue:
when I turn on a flat mode for category, thumbnail and image for all category are empty. For example:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}

require_once $mageFilename;
//important
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(3));

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(15791118);
print_r($category);
```

Image and thumbnail are empty.

If I turn off a flat mode for category, image and thumbnail has values.
For each change of catalog mode I turn on reindex.

In catalog_category_flat_3 fields image (attribute id: 45) and thumbnail (attribute id: 133) are null.

Comment: Did you rebuild the flat index after adding the image?

Comment: Yes, I rebuild this. Catalog category flat mode doesn't copy image,thumbnail, meta fields to catalog category flat table.

Comment: Do the columns exist?

Comment: Yes, in EAV mode I have no null image, thumbnail value.